# RGSS in RPG Maker VX Ace-

Tags: ruby

I have been using a pack of scripts, textures and audio for RPG Maker VX Ace called Pokémon for Ace. I have been succeeding to fix some errors, but this one I could not fix. 
I get this error in the console:

```
Item Effects:216:in `block in extra_evs': private method `extra_evs' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from Item Effects:216:in `each'
    from Item Effects:216:in `inject'
    from Item Effects:216:in `extra_evs'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4403:in `block (3 levels) in process_action_end'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4392:in `each'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4392:in `block (2 levels) in process_action_end'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4379:in `each'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4379:in `block in process_action_end'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4373:in `each'
    from Pokémon Battle System:4373:in `process_action_end'
    from Mega Evolution:453:in `process_action'
    from Scene_Battle:48:in `update'
    from Pokedex:1746:in `update'
    from Party Dying Battle BGM:130:in `update'
    from Scene_Base:14:in `main'
    from MOG_Weather_EX:694:in `main'
    from Graphical Object Global Reference:201:in `main'
    from Video Player:153:in `run'
    from Map Screenshot:971:in `run'
    from Screenshot taker:215:in `run'
    from Main:12:in `block in <main>'
```

Here' s the code of the part that gives errors:

```
class Game_Battler < Game_BattlerBase
    attr_accessor :attacking_item
  attr_accessor :captured
    def extra_evs(stat)
        equips.inject(0) {|r, equip| r += equip.extra_evs(stat)}
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `equips` array contains a nil value. Check where it is being assigned.

For dirty fix, try `equips.compact.inject(0) {|r, equip| r += equip.extra_evs(stat)}`

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you!

Comment: @MyHousedStudios :) gimme an accept answer thanks.
Also I still recommend finding the root cause of why there is a nil in your equips.